# How to change the color of the matched substring?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

[image]

What property is responsible for the color matched substring and selects the current item and where is it located?

[image]

**update images**

[image]

Comment: What function is this?

Comment: @Jongware: I don't know the name of these functions.

Comment: It seems to me that in order to be a visually consistent feature the color of the matched string is the same as the color of the rest of the string but using bold style and maybe a different opacity.

Comment: @Jongware First function is goto-anything (Ctrl-P). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @sergioFC: possible. but where and which property you want to change to change the color? I want to be like this - [now add the third img]

Comment: @Jongware: 1) ctrl + p || ctrl + shift + p 2) SublimeCodeIntel

Comment: @sergioFC: You've probably made a mistake. On the last picture the main text white, and blue highlighting.

Comment: @shatal You're right, I haven't seen the updated image.

Comment: I've found it. Look at *selected_match_fg* and *selected_fg*

Comment: @sergioFC: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you get started, if you're using Sublime Text 3 (and you *really* should be), you'll need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) so you can edit the appropriate files. To change the coloring, you need to first open the `.sublime-theme` file that is currently active. If you are using the default settings, it is `Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme`. If you are using a third-party theme, the path will be in your user preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**). Open the Command Palette, type ***`prv`*** to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options, then select `Extract Package` and pick the one you're interested in. It will be extracted to your `Packages` folder, which can be opened in your operating system's file manager by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**. Open the `.sublime-theme` file in Sublime and set the syntax to JSON.

Once you've opened the file, search for `selected_match_fg` - in both `Default` and `Soda Dark 3` there should be 3 instances, in the following classes: `quick_panel_label`, `quick_panel_path_label`, and `auto_complete_label`. For example, this is from `Soda Dark 3`:

```js
{
    "class": "quick_panel_label",
    "fg": [210, 210, 210, 255],
    "match_fg": [126, 199, 239, 255],
    "selected_fg": [255, 255, 255, 255],
    "selected_match_fg": [166, 229, 255, 255]
},
```

Each setting should be pretty self-explanatory. The values are in RGB(A) format (the alpha setting is optional) using decimal values (0-255). Edit them as you wish, then save the file and restart Sublime - this is necessary because themes are not necessarily completely reloaded upon changing.

(Thanks to [sergioFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625580/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-matched-substring#comment51200709_31625580) for the pointer to the relevant settings.)

Comment: Thanks again @sergioFC and to You separate thanks for the PackageResourceViewer.

Comment: @shatal no problem, glad to help.